# Multiplying elements in a lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to duplicate an specific element as many times as indicated.

The original list would look like this:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And here would have to be the duplicator and the element of the list that we want to duplicate.

```
times=4
num=4
```

The final list would have to look like this:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: A simple for loop line will do the needful. Please find out its very easy. Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
ex_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

times=4
num=4

new_list = sorted(ex_list + [ex_list[ex_list.index(times)]] * (num-1))
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Why so many downvotes? It's essentially the same as JBernardo's in a single line and before his, so it's not like I copy-pasted his good answer...

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because it fails if the original list is not sorted. `ex_list = [5,6,4,1]` yields `[1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6]` which doesn't seem to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it and if your list only have one occurrence of the number this is likely the simplest way

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
num = 4
times = 4

ix = lst.index(num)
lst[ix:ix+1] = [num] * times
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use list repetition and concatenation:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

times = 4
num = 4

ind = lst.index(num)
result = lst[:ind] + [num] * times + lst[ind + 1:]

print(result)
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```